# Modify core dump disk space utilization per node

Tags: linux, kubernetes, linux-kernel, systemd, coredump

As per the official man page documentation for coredump.conf, the core dump disk space utilization per node in Kubernetes can be modified by changing the MaxUse section to X%, and by default, it is 10%.

https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/coredump.conf.5.html

I have done the following things :

- 1st Solution which I tried: Modified `/etc/systemd/coredump.conf` by removing # before MaxUse and changes it to 20%

  ```
  cat /etc/systemd/coredump.conf
  MaxUse=20%
  ```

  ---

  After that, I ran "sudo systemctl daemon-reload" in order to reflect the change but it didn't work.
- 2nd Solution which I tried : Adding `/etc/systemd/coredump.conf.d/custom.conf` to override `/etc/systemd/coredump.conf`. This option was specified here: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Core_dump

  ```
  [Coredump]
  MaxUse=20%
  ```

  ---

  After that, I ran "sudo systemctl daemon-reload" in order to reflect the change but it didn't work.
  I did multiple cores just to check whether both solutions are working but it didn't work:

  I have core my test application and just to get large cores I have used the below-mentioned command:

  ```
  $ sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=abc.xz bs=1024 count=10240000
  ```

  While testing this my core dump directory `/var/lib/systemd/coredump/` had over 150G of core.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the [docs](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/coredump.conf.5.html) [are misleading](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/424167/54556) and say that it defaults to `MaxUse` to be 10%. But it seems like the [systemd code](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/4e4e3d97664163267d8295e6f58e0ff8560bea33/src/basic/parse-util.c#L109) shows that it's parsed in terms of Bytes, Kbytes, Mbytes, etc. You can try something like:

```
[Coredump]
MaxUse=20G
```

Comment: I have tried using MaxUse=20G but it doesn't work. I am able to create core dumps with cumulative more then 20G in total size.

Comment: Can you elaborate how this `sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=abc.xz bs=1024 count=10240000` creates core dumps?

Comment: It basically create a fake large coredump files using the "dd" linux command in /var/lib/systemd/coredump/ directory as I do not have the means to create a large core dump. My test application just create a core dump of few Mb.

Comment: I don't think dd triggers the core dump mechanism from the kernel, what makes you think that?

Comment: I think that's a valid point,  let me just test it and I will provide you with the result :)

Comment: Yeah, try setting `MaxUse` to something smaller than 2 of your core files.

Comment: Thanks @Rico for the solution. I have tested it and it works fine :)